# Large files as a POST request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm developing a program that encodes images as base64 strings, then submits those strings as parameters of a POST request to an API server. It works with very small images (under 1kb), but when I try to use my 54kb test image, it fails. I just get no response from the API server. I know this is possible, as other devs have gotten it to work, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code for the section in question:

```
dlimage = requests.get(imageURL, stream=True, timeout=10)
encodedImage = base64.encodestring(dlimage.content)
imagequery = {"request":"saveProductPicture","sessionKey":sessionKey,"clientCode":clientCode,"productID":productID,"picture":encodedImage}
response = requests.request("POST", url, params=imagequery, stream=True, timeout=10)
```

Comment: Your text says POST, but your code says GET.  Which method are you actually using?

Comment: My mistake. Corrected code.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem. using params essentially forces the request to be treated as a GET. For a POST request, data should be used instead of params.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what web server you're using, but it's likely the server is imposing a limit on the request size.

If you're using Apache, see [LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody).

For nginx, see [client_max_body_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size).

For lighttpd, see [server.max-request-size](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Server_max-request-sizeDetails).

I can't find a setting for unicorn (dev server).

In any case, if you're having trouble, check your server log files. There may also be a setting in your Python web framework, but you didn't specify which one you're using. In my experience, it's usually the external web server that's imposing the limit.